# Calculate ETA in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm attempting to calculate the estimated travel time (walking) between two locations in swift, the user to an annotation.

Here is my current code, it does not throw any errors that crash the program but only returns "Error while requesting ETA"

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationObjects: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

/*let userView = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude)
 let annotationPoint = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
 let distance = userView.distance(from: annotationPoint)*/


var identifier = "bathroom location"
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var distance: Double
var phoneNumber: String
var addressFinished: String
var estimatedTravelTime: String


// Request ETA function
// Uses user location and destination to send request
// For Estimated time of arrival
class func requestETA(userCLLocation: CLLocation, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> String {

    var travelTime = String()

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    /* Source MKMapItem */
    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: userCLLocation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
    request.source = sourceItem
    /* Destination MKMapItem */
    let destinationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
    request.destination = destinationItem
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    // Looking for walking directions
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.walking

    // You use the MKDirectionsRequest object constructed above to initialise an MKDirections object
    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculateETA { (etaResponse, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error while requesting ETA : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            travelTime = "Not Available"
        }else{
            print("No error requesting ETA")
            travelTime = "\(Int((etaResponse?.expectedTravelTime)!/60)) min"
        }
    }

    return travelTime
}


init(name:String,lat:CLLocationDegrees,long:CLLocationDegrees,userCLLocation:CLLocation, phone:String, address:String){
    title = name
    coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    distance = Double(String(format: "%.2f", (userCLLocation.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)))*0.000621371))!
    phoneNumber = phone
    addressFinished = address
    estimatedTravelTime = LocationObjects.requestETA(userCLLocation: userCLLocation, coordinate: coordinate)

}
}
```

The console looks something like this for an exceedingly long amount of lines

```
    2017-05-26 13:53:51.583 Toilet Locator[2568:181698] didFailWithError Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-3 "(null)" UserInfo={GEORequestThrottleStateLevel=0, GEORequestThrottleStateResetTimeRemaining=34.019131004810333}
2017-05-26 13:53:51.584 Toilet Locator[2568:181698] didFailWithError Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-3 "(null)" UserInfo={GEORequestThrottleStateLevel=0, GEORequestThrottleStateResetTimeRemaining=34.018206000328064}
Error while requesting ETA : Directions Not Available
Error while requesting ETA : Directions Not Available
```

I'm hoping for some guidance, thank you all!

Note: ViewController calls this class to be made many times in a row so not sure if that would cause Apple to reject ETA requests?

Comment: Can you add code showing how you're calling that function?

Comment: Every five seconds a timer fires off a function using an MKLocalSearch request. Any annotation that is not added to the map (could be 10+) is being initialized into this "LocationObjects" class one after another which throws "Error while requesting ETA : Directions Not Available" for each object of this class.

Comment: Based on the wording of the error `userInfo` (`GEORequestThrottleStateLevel`, `GEORequestThrottleStateResetTimeRemaining`) it does sound like Apple limits how many times you can call the routing API. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like this error info is documented (that I can see) so I would recommend trying to limit the number of calls you make. For example, instead of using a timer, only call the API when the user's location changes (and use `distanceFilter` on `CLLocationManager`) and limiting the number of objects you put into this class.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I'll have to find a work around to calling it so many times.