# Check Which Annotation Callout is Opening

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I'm working on a project where I need to find the estimated travel time from the user location to a certain MKAnnotation. I would like to be able to see which annotation the user has clicked on so I can generate the ETA and display it on the annotationCalloutView using the "viewFor annotation" function.

This ETA cannot be calculated using a custom MKAnnotation class due throttling from Apple if done in this way: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208558/calculate-eta-in-swift) So it must be done while the annotation callout is opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `mapView` delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

}
```

You have the parameter `view` which is the clicked `MKAnnotationView` and from that parameter you can access your `annotation`.